# Use a string from an outside class to the main class

Tags: java

I have a main class file that calls methods as objects from other outside class files.

I'm having a hard time using a string in the main class file that was defined in an outside class file.

This is the main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TW5K
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        CiteNum citenumber = new CiteNum();
        PlateNum platenumber = new PlateNum();
        DateNum datenumber = new DateNum();

        citenumber.CiteEnt();
        platenumber.PlateEnt();
        datenumber.DateEnt();

        System.out.println(); // I want to print the string "dateld" here, from the outside class.
    }
}
```

This is the outside class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DateNum
{
    public void DateEnt()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter date of violation: ");
        String dateld = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your formatting is horrendous, please fix it

Comment: Apart from the formatting, please describe your high-level problem, since you are clearly not having the right approach (think encapsulation, think OOP, think Java)

Comment: Have the DateEnt() method return a String, capture that in your calling class and print it. btw, convention is to camelCase method names.
You also need to rethink your class structure as Dici mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Return the value:

```
public String DateEnt()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter date of violation: ");
    String dateld = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println();
    return dateld;
}
```

Then:

```
String dateld = datenumber.DateEnt();

System.out.println(dateld);
```

Comment: I appreciate the tips and criticism very much, you can probably tell I am so green to Java... Just barely scratching the surface. Thank you for the answer, I promise not to abuse this resource of asking.